# Doubly-linked list in C++ - insertFirst vs. insertLast implementation

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

In my implementation of a doubly-linked list in C++, I can't understand why in `insertFirst`, you **always** need to to do `pNewLink->pNext = pFirst` but in `insertLast` you **only** do `pNewLink->pPrevious = pLast` if the list isn't empty? Otherwise it seems like the two methods seem to be exact opposites of each other.

```
void insertFirst(double dd) //insert at front of list
{
    Link* pNewLink = new Link(dd);

    if( isEmpty() ) 
        pLast = pNewLink;
    else
        pFirst->pPrevious = pNewLink;

    pNewLink->pNext = pFirst;
    pFirst = pNewLink;
}


void insertLast(double dd)  //insert at end of list
{
    Link* pNewLink = new Link(dd);

    if( isEmpty() )
        pFirst = pNewLink;
    else
    {
        pLast->pPrevious = pLast;
        pNewLink->pPrevious = pLast;
    }

    pLast = pNewLink;
}
```

Comment: *In my implementation of a doubly-linked list in C++, I can't understand why...* -- Before writing a single line of code, you should have drawn, with lines and boxes, the operations that would need to be done to insert into a linked list.  Then there would be no issue in what would need to be done.  Completing a linked list assignment (assuming this is homework) all depends on pictorially making the design first, and not trying to code your way to a solution.

Comment: I'm just getting my feet wet in programming. This code snippet is taken from "Learn Data Structures in 24 Hours". After browsing a bit here, it looks like these books are not recommended even for a preview (and the unreliable code seems like it would waste my time). Thanks for your tip though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your implementation seems incorrect as you should not set `pNewLink->pNext` in `insertFirst` when the list is empty.

If you do this modification, both method will look like more "symetric".

If you insert last. You don't have "next value" so you don't set it but you have previous value so you set this.

If you insert first, you don't have "previous value" so you don't set it but you have a next value so you set this.